# Loss of type info in servlet code

Tags: scala

I have a simple flash implementation for use with Jersey that looks like this:

```scala
@PostConstruct def before { flash.rotateIn }
@PreDestroy def after { flash.rotateOut }

object flash {
  val KeyNow  = "local.flash.now"
  val KeyNext = "local.flash.next"

  // case class Wrapper(wrapped: Map[String, Seq[String]])
  case class Wrapper(wrapped: String)

  def rotateIn {
    for {
      session <- Option(request.getSession(false))
      obj     <- Option(session.getAttribute(KeyNext))
    } {
      request.setAttribute(KeyNow, obj)
      session.removeAttribute(KeyNext)
    }
  }

  def rotateOut {
    for (obj <- Option(request.getAttribute(KeyNext))) {
      request.getSession.setAttribute(KeyNext, obj)
    }
  }

  def now = Option(request.getAttribute(KeyNow)) match {
    case Some(x: Wrapper) => x.wrapped
    case Some(x) if x.isInstanceOf[Wrapper] => "WHAT"
    case _ => "NOPE"
  }

  def next(value: String) {
    request.setAttribute(KeyNext, Wrapper(value))
  }
}
```

I have simplified it here somewhat, but it lets me set a value for flash with `flash.next` and read the current flash value with `flash.now`.

The weird thing is that my `now` value is always "WHAT". If I do something similar in my REPL, I don't have the same issues:

```scala
val req = new org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest
val res = req.getSession
res.setAttribute("foo", Wrapper("foo"))
req.setAttribute("foo", res.getAttribute("foo"))
// Is not None
Option(req.getAttribute("foo")).collect { case x: Wrapper => x }
```

Am I missing something obvious?

**EDIT**

I've added a minimal example webapp replicating this issue at https://github.com/kardeiz/sc-issue-20160229.

Comment: Does `case Some(x):Option[Wrapper] => x.wrapped` work? (didn't test it). Your REPL session isn't doing the same thing as your code (it's just testing `x` is a `Wrapper`, not that `x` in `Some(x)` is a `Wrapper`)

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul That doesn't compile, but thanks

Comment: OK. thanks for telling me, Sorry for not testing.

Comment: The answer is, "No, you're not missing something obvious." Something not obvious, maybe. I got your example to show both WHAT and NOPE. ha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your example. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35710538/1349366) for your other question for details how pattern matching works in this case.

In short, as you `Wrapper` is an inner class, patter matching also checks the "outer class" reference. It seems that depending on the application server implementation `Router.flash` can be different instance for each request, so pattern matching fails.

Simple fix for that is to make `Wrapper` top-level class, so it doesn't have reference to any other class.

Comment: Thank you! I've confirmed that moving `Wrapper` out of the `Router` class resolves the issue.