# Weird pattern match issue

Tags: scala

Assuming `Foo` is a simple case class, in what cases will the value of the following expression be `2`?

```
Option(myFoo) match { 
  case Some(x: Foo) => 1
  case Some(x) if x.isInstanceOf[Foo] => 2
  case _ => 3
}
```

See [Loss of type info in servlet code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639950/loss-of-type-info-in-servlet-code) for the context for this question.

Comment: The use case is probably inseparable from what you link to. That is, probably you can't show this example in a single-threaded context like the REPL? Not that I disbelieve the linked case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and second cases are equivalent.

Here is you function decompiled back to java (using [scala-to-java](https://github.com/Aivean/scala-to-java)):

Scala:

```
type Foo = String
def test(foo:Any) = Option(foo) match {
  case Some(x: Foo) => 1
  case Some(x) if x.isInstanceOf[Foo] => 2
  case _ => 3
}
```

Java:

```
import scala.*;

public final class _$$anon$1 {
    private int test(final Object foo) {
        boolean b = false;
        Some<Object> some = null;
        final Option<Object> apply = Option$.MODULE$.apply(foo);
        if (apply instanceof Some) {
            b = true;
            some = (Some<Object>)apply;
            final Object x = some.x();
            if (x instanceof String) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        if (b) {
            final Object x2 = some.x();
            if (x2 instanceof String) {
                return 2;
            }
        }
        return 3;
    }
}
```

---

**Update!**

It appears that pattern matching works differently for inner classes:

```
case class Wrapper(wrapped: String)

def test(a:Any) = Option(a) match {
  case Some(x:Wrapper) => x
  case Some(x) if x.isInstanceOf[Wrapper] => x
  case x => ???
}
```

Produces something like this:

```
private Object test(final Object a) {
    boolean b = false;
    Some<Object> some = null;
    final Option<Object> apply = Option$.MODULE$.apply(a);
    if (apply instanceof Some) {
        b = true;
        some = (Some<Object>)apply;
        final Object x = some.x();
        if (x instanceof _$$anon$1$Wrapper && ((_$$anon$1$Wrapper)x)._$$anon$Wrapper$$$outer() == this) {
            return x;
        }
    }
    if (b) {
        final Object x2 = some.x();
        if (x2 instanceof _$$anon$1$Wrapper) {
            return x2;
        }
    }
    throw Predef$.MODULE$.$qmark$qmark$qmark();
}
```

So, it checks also the "outer" field, i.e. the outer class. If you are not in control of your environment, as in case where you can't guarantee that outer class is always the same instance, pattern matching may fail (and that's very upsetting to discover).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is really weird though--doesn't that mean it should be unreachable? I have some code that definitely matches the second case. I've put a minimal example at https://github.com/kardeiz/sc-issue-20160229/ if you or anyone else would be willing to take a look

Comment: Whoa, tricky! That makes sense though I guess. Thanks so much for tracking this down!

Answer (score -1):

In the case that x is Not an instance of Foo class, say Any type but Foo type. But sorry it will not be 2 in any case as long as there if x.isInstanceOf[Foo] which make case 1 and case2 are the same case.
assuming you have this code

```
def f(t:Any) = Option(t) match {
  case Some(x: Foo) => 1
  case Some(x) if x.isInstanceOf[Foo] => 2
  case _ => 3
}
```